# Tensorflow - Is it possible to manually decide which tensors in a graph go to the GPU and CPU?

Tags: parallel-processing, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I've created a network in Keras that uses both convolutional and LSTM layers.

And I've read that tensorflow can't handle well the LSTM layers in GPU: http://minimaxir.com/2017/07/cpu-or-gpu/

In fact, my network got slow in the GPU (hoping its not a further problem).

I want tensorflow to throw all convolutional operations to the GPU, but keep all the LSTM operations in the CPU. Is that possible?

So, considering I can find the tensorflow graph and identify each of its tensors, can I define manually where each tensor performs its operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following implementation of [this](https://github.com/allanzelener/YAD2K/blob/1ebda3e58503d29d6c5232c934e6b60be4b423b7/train_overfit.py) network, you could (if you use `Tensorflow`) try the following technique:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # model layers which should be run on CPU go here
```

Comment: Great! This made my model finish its job still in this life.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this document: [Distributed TensorFlow Specifying distributed devices in your model](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/distributed/#specifying_distributed_devices_in_your_model)